# How can I find the closest marker with Google Maps Direction Service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am working on a google maps project where I am populating the google maps with markers being read from a database (drawMarkers function). Along with that the google maps finds your current location and keeps refreshing it every couple of seconds to keep track of you on the map. My issue is that have a var closest which is also a function i am using the too find the closest marker then create directions to current locations from there. I did not know how to actually find the closest marker so i borrowed the code from another question from stack overflow and tried to adapt it to this project. I need help to get my closest function to find the closest marker and then to make it the destination in the direction service

```
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);

$scope.getTourMarkers = function () {
    tourmarkers.getTourMarkers().success(function (data) {
        $scope.tourmarkers = data;
        console.log($scope.tourmarkers);
        drawMarkers();
    });
};


var drawMarkers = function () {

    var markers;
    var content;
    var infoWindow;


    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tourmarkers.length; i++) {
        content = '<h2>' + $scope.tourmarkers[i].title + '</h2>' +
            '<br />' +
            '<p>' +

            '</p>';

        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content
        });

        var point = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.tourmarkers[i].lat, $scope.tourmarkers[i].lon);

        markers = new google.maps.Marker({
            label: "S",
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: point,
            map: map,
            info: content
    });

        //SCOPE: 'this' refers to the current 'markers' object, we pass in the info and marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.setContent(this.info);
            infoWindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }

};

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.5602, -121.4241);
var NAPA_HALL_LAT_LNG = new google.maps.LatLng(38.553801, -121.4212745); // just created this marker for testing purposes

var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoomControl: true,
    disableDefaultUI: true
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'SAC STATE'
});

var dest = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: NAPA_HALL_LAT_LNG,
    map: map,
    title: 'NAPA HALL'
});

///////////////////Directions Display//////////////////////
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Goal of this function is to find closest marker to current location
//then to create directions to that marker.
//should be refreshed everytime in the onSuccess function
var closest = function (directionsService, directionsDisplay, marker, dest) {

    var event;

    function rad(x) {return x*Math.PI/180;}

    function find_closest_marker( event ) {
        var lat = event.latLng.lat();
        var lng = event.latLng.lng();
        var R = 6371;                           // radius of earth in km
        var distances = [];
        var shortest = -1;


        for( i=0;i < $scope.tourmarkers.length; i++) {
        content = '<h2>' + $scope.tourmarkers[i].title + '</h2>' +
            '<br />' +
            '<p>' +

            '</p>';

        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

        var mlat = $scope.tourmarkers[i].position.lat();
        var mlng = $scope.tourmarkers[i].position.lng();
        var dLat  = rad(mlat - lat);
        var dLong = rad(mlng - lng);
        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(rad(lat)) * Math.cos(rad(lat)) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        var d = R * c;
        distances[i] = d;
        if ( shortest == -1 || d < distances[shortest] ) {
            shortest = i;
        }
    }

    alert(map.markers[shortest].title);
}

    /////**directions feature should have the closest marker be the desitination//
    directionsService.route({
        origin: marker.position,  
        destination: dest.position,               // i think the marker that should in here is shortest.
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
    }, function(response,status) {
        if(status==google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  

var onSuccess = function (position) {

    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    dest.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(38.553801, -121.4212745));
    //dest.setPosition((closest(marker, $scope.tourmarkers)).position);  // if you can get this line to work without commenting it out then you're set
    closest(directionsService,directionsDisplay, marker,dest);
    $scope.map = map;
    //$scope.map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
};

function onError(error) {
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
        'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, {
    maximumAge: 3000,
    timeout: 5000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true
});
```

Everything in this project is working properly except that closest function. but even then i have already tested the directionservice and even that is working too. I just need help making the destination in the direction service to be the closest marker to current location.

Answer (score -1):

i think this code is helpful for you i used this code in my project such that your requirement same as my requirement

**in the below function 'data' means list of lat lng's from server**

```
function initialize(data) {
    size = 0;
    counts = 0;
    stops = data;
    size = stops.length;

        if (stops.length > 0) {
            var map = new window.google.maps.Map(document
                    .getElementById("map"));
            // new up complex objects before passing them around
            var directionsDisplay = new window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(
                    {
                        suppressMarkers : true,
                        polylineOptions : {
                            strokeColor : "black"
                        }
                    });
            var directionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();
            Tour_startUp(stops);
            window.tour.loadMap(map, directionsDisplay);
            window.tour.fitBounds(map,stops);
            /* if (stops.length > 1) */
                window.tour.calcRoute(stops,directionsService,
                        directionsDisplay,size);
        }
}


function Tour_startUp(stops) {
    var stops=stops;
    var counts=0;
    if (!window.tour) window.tour = {
        // map: google map object
        // directionsDisplay: google directionsDisplay object (comes in empty)
        loadMap: function (map, directionsDisplay) {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom:10,
                center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(17.379818, 78.478542), // default to Hyderabad
                mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map.setOptions(myOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        },
        fitBounds: function (map,stops) {
            var bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            // extend bounds for each record

            jQuery.each(stops, function (key, val) {
                var myLatlng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(val.latitude, val.longitude);
                bounds.extend(myLatlng);
            });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);

        },
        calcRoute: function (stops,directionsService, directionsDisplay,size) {
            size=size;
            var batches = [];
            var itemsPerBatch = 10; // google API max = 10 - 1 start, 1 stop, and 8 waypoints
            var itemsCounter = 0;
            var wayptsExist = stops.length > 0;
            var tempp=0;
            while (wayptsExist) {
                var subBatch = [];
                var subitemsCounter = 0;

                for (var j = itemsCounter; j < stops.length; j++) {
                    subitemsCounter++;
                    tempp++;
                    subBatch.push({

                        location: new window.google.maps.LatLng(stops[j].latitude, stops[j].longitude),
                        stopover: true
                    });
                    if (subitemsCounter == itemsPerBatch)
                        break;
                }
                itemsCounter += subitemsCounter;
                batches.push(subBatch);
                wayptsExist = itemsCounter < stops.length;
                // If it runs again there are still points. Minus 1 before continuing to
                // start up with end of previous tour leg
                itemsCounter--;
            }

            // now we should have a 2 dimensional array with a list of a list of waypoints
            var combinedResults;
            var unsortedResults = [{}]; // to hold the counter and the results themselves as they come back, to later sort
            var directionsResultsReturned = 0;

            for (var k = 0; k < batches.length; k++) {
                var lastIndex = batches[k].length - 1;
                var start = batches[k][0].location;
               //delay(600); 
                var end = batches[k][lastIndex].location;


                // trim first and last entry from array
                var waypts = [];
                waypts = batches[k];
                waypts.splice(0, 1);
                waypts.splice(waypts.length - 1, 1);

                var request = {
                    origin: start,
                    destination: end,
                    waypoints: waypts,
                    travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
                };
                (function (kk) {
                    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                        if (status == window.google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            var unsortedResult = { order: kk, result: result };
                            unsortedResults.push(unsortedResult);
                            //alert("count test");
                            directionsResultsReturned++;
                            if (directionsResultsReturned == batches.length) // we've received all the results. put to map
                            {
                                // sort the returned values into their correct order
                                unsortedResults.sort(function (a, b) { return parseFloat(a.order) - parseFloat(b.order); });
                                var count = 0;
                                for (var key in unsortedResults) {
                                    if (unsortedResults[key].result != null) {
                                        if (unsortedResults.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                            if (count == 0) // first results. new up the combinedResults object
                                                combinedResults = unsortedResults[key].result;
                                            else {
                                                // only building up legs, overview_path, and bounds in my consolidated object. This is not a complete
                                                // directionResults object, but enough to draw a path on the map, which is all I need
                                                combinedResults.routes[0].legs = combinedResults.routes[0].legs.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].legs);
                                                combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path = combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].overview_path);

                                                combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getNorthEast());
                                                combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getSouthWest());
                                            }
                                            count++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                directionsDisplay.setDirections(combinedResults);
                                var legs = combinedResults.routes[0].legs;
                                var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_panel');
                                summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
                                var totdist=0;
                                for (var i=0; i < legs.length;i++){

                                     var markerletter = "A".charCodeAt(0);
                                     var markerletter2= "B".charCodeAt(0)
                                         markerletter += i;
                                    markerletter2 += i; 
                                  markerletter = String.fromCharCode(markerletter);
                                  markerletter2 = String.fromCharCode(markerletter2);
                                  createMarker(directionsDisplay.getMap(),legs[i].start_location,legs[i].start_address,markerletter,size);//To display location address on the marker
                                  var routeSegment = i + 1;
                                  var point=+routeSegment+1;
                                  summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment + '</b><br>';
                                  summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Point '+ routeSegment +' :</b>'+ '  ' +legs[i].start_address + ' <br> ';
                                  summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Point '+ point +' :</b>'+ '  '+legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
                                  summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Distance Covered '+' :</b>'+legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
                                  var test=legs[i].distance.text.split(' ');
                                  var one=parseFloat(test[0]);
                                if(test[1]=="m"){
                                  var one=parseFloat(test[0]/1000); 
                                  }
                                  totdist=parseFloat(totdist)+parseFloat(one);
                                }
                                summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b> Total Distance :'+totdist + 'km'+ '</b><br><br>';
                                var i=legs.length;
                                var markerletter = "A".charCodeAt(0);
                    markerletter += i;
                                markerletter = String.fromCharCode(markerletter);
                                createMarker(directionsDisplay.getMap(),legs[legs.length-1].end_location,legs[legs.length-1].end_address,markerletter,size);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                })(k);
                function delay(ms) {
                       ms += new Date().getTime();
                       while (new Date() < ms){}
                    }
            }
        }//calculate route end
    };
}



//to show information on clicking marker
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { 
    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
  }); 


var icons = new Array();
icons["red"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("mapIcons/marker_red.png",
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));



function getMarkerImage(iconStr,size) {
    counts++;
     if(counts==size){
        var markerimageLoc = "http://www.maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png";
        counts = 0;
    }else{
   if (iconStr=="undefined") { 
      iconStr = "red"; 
      var markerimageLoc = "http://www.maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png"; 
   }
   else{
        var markerimageLoc="http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker"+ iconStr +".png"; 
      //  var markerimageLoc = "http://www.maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png";   
   }
    }
      icons[iconStr] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(markerimageLoc,
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(25, 34),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
   return icons[iconStr];

}
  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
  // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
  // in the top left of the image.

  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
  // increase in the X direction to the right and in
  // the Y direction down.

  var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
      // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
      // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
      new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
      // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
      // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
      // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
      // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
      // coordinate.
  var iconShape = {
      coord: [9,0,6,1,4,2,2,4,0,8,0,12,1,14,2,16,5,19,7,23,8,26,9,30,9,34,11,34,11,30,12,26,13,24,14,21,16,18,18,16,20,12,20,8,18,4,16,2,15,1,13,0],
      type: 'poly'
  };

function createMarker(map, latlng, label, character,size) {
        var markerletter = character;
        var size=size;
         if (/[^a-zA-Z]/.test(character)) {
            var markerletter = "undefined";
        }
        var contentString = '<b>' + label + '</b><br>';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : latlng,
            map : map,
            shadow : iconShadow,
            icon : getMarkerImage(markerletter,size),
            shape : iconShape,
            title : label,
            zIndex : Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
        });
        marker.myname = label;

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        return marker;
    }
```